# Xcode 11.4 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError was called when registering for push notifications

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

Seems like an Xcode bug. I'm on 11.4 and my simulator is on 13.4. For some reason, the fail handler is triggering.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            granted,
            _ in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func application(_: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
       print("registed")
    }

    func application(_: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        assertionFailure(String(describing: error))
    }
```

Error: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}`